# Letting user to specify where the excel file should be exported in vb 2010

Tags: vb.net

I have a database app that exports data in datagridview to excel. it all works fine but i want my user to specify the path where the excel will be exported. 
can you give me some answers or hints? TIA
here is my code for the export button.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim columnsCount As Integer = DataGridView1.Columns.Count

    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value

    xlWorkBook = APP.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    For Each column In DataGridView1.Columns
        xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, column.Index + 1).Value = column.Name
    Next

    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim columnIndex As Integer = 0
        Do Until columnIndex = columnsCount
            xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 2, columnIndex + 1).Value = DataGridView1.Item(columnIndex, i).Value.ToString
            columnIndex += 1
        Loop
    Next

    xlWorkBook.SaveAs("C:\Users\IT-PC\Desktop\Excel Files for Printing\Metal\Metal.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, _
     Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue)
    xlWorkBook.Close(True, misValue, misValue)
    APP.Quit()

    releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)
    releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
    releaseObject(APP)

    MessageBox.Show("File successfully exported!")
End Sub
```

Comment: That would be exactly what a `SaveFileDialog` is for.

Comment: ok. I'll study it. Thank you jmcilhinney.

Answer (score 0):

add a module and paste the code below, and uses the function GetSaveTo("filename",["where to save"]), if the return ="" then user has click on cancel.

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function GetSaveFileName Lib "comdlg32.dll" Alias "GetSaveFileNameA" (pOpenFilename As OPENFILENAME) As Long

Private Type OPENFILENAME
    lStructSize As Long
    hwndOwner As Long
    hInstance As Long
    lpstrFilter As String
    lpstrCustomFilter As String
    nMaxCustFilter As Long
    nFilterIndex As Long
    lpstrFile As String
    nMaxFile As Long
    lpstrFileTitle As String
    nMaxFileTitle As Long
    lpstrInitialDir As String
    lpstrTitle As String
    flags As Long
    nFileOffset As Integer
    nFileExtension As Integer
    lpstrDefExt As String
    lCustData As Long
    lpfnHook As Long
    lpTemplateName As String
End Type

Dim m_OpenFilename As OPENFILENAME
Const MaxBuffer = 256
Const OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT = &H2&



public Function GetSaveTo(ByVal fname As String, Optional ByVal InitialDir As String) As String
    If (InitialDir = "") Then InitialDir = Environ("userprofile")

    With m_OpenFilename
        .lStructSize = Len(m_OpenFilename)

        .lpstrTitle = "Save to"
        .lpstrInitialDir = InitialDir
        .flags = OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT
        .lpstrFilter = "Excel Workbook" & Chr(0) & "*.xlsx" & Chr(0) & Chr(0)
        .nFilterIndex = 1

        .lpstrFile = String(MaxBuffer, 0)
        .nMaxFile = MaxBuffer - 1
        .lpstrFileTitle = .lpstrFile
        .nMaxFileTitle = MaxBuffer - 1

    End With
    If GetSaveFileName(m_OpenFilename) <> 0 Then
        GetSaveTo = Left$(m_OpenFilename.lpstrFile, m_OpenFilename.nMaxFile)
    End If
End Function
```